# Efficient way to map a subset of entity fields as separate class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm designing a solution for dealing with complex structure (user related stuff with lots of relations) in a simplier and possibly more efficient way than getting all the related data from DB. The only part of data I really need in my use case is basically contained withing the non-relational 'main' entity fields.

As for now I extracted the basic fields from 'main' class (let it be class OldMain) to another class (let's call it abstract class Extracted), used @MappedSuperclass and created 2 classes that extends it- Basic (which is empty class as Extracted gives it all the data I need and mapped to table 'X') and Extended (which is also mapped to table 'X' but with all the extra relations). It basically works but the code structure looks odd and makes me thinking if that's a proper way of dealing with such a problem.

I also tried with lazy initiation on relational fields (which i guessed on the beginning would serve here well), but I wasn't able to get it to work as I wanted with Jackson (only non-lazy fields in JSON, without fetching lazy related data- it couldn't be serialized or fired another several dozen of relation queries).

Another thing i stumbled upon in some tutorial was making DTO from 'OldMain' entity to not touch the lazy fields but haven't tried it yet as I started with the @MappedSuperClass way.

```java
@Table(name = "X")
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Extracted{
    //all the non-relational fields from OldMain
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
}
```

```java
@Table(name = "X")
@Entity
public class Basic extends Extracted{
    //empty
}
```

```java
@Table(name = "X")
@Entity
public class Extended extends Extracted{
    //all relational fields from OldMain, no data fields
}
```

Also the general question is- is there any good practices when dealing with need of using only a subset of a bigger entity?

Comment: If you use Spring Data, Spring Data projections can accomplish what I think you want.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 2):

There is no obligation for a JPA Entity to map all existing columns in the corresponding table in the database. That is, given a table `my_entity` with columns `col1, col2, col3`, the Entity mapped to this table could map only `col1` and `col2` and ignore `col3`. That being said, plus the fact that you only need the non-relational attributes, you could directly use your `Extracted` class with the attributes you need and ignore the fact that other relational field exists. Furthermore, if all the relational fields are nullable then you could even be able to persist new instances of `Extracted` class. And Jackson would only (un)marshal the declared attributes in `Extracted` class.

In other case, I suggest to follow the approach you already are in and define new Entity classes that extend your `Extracted` class with the required attributes. I don't see how "code structure looks odd", other than having a `Basic` class with no new attributes than `Extracted` - you could easily make `Extracted` non-abstract and use it directly, and get rid of `Basic`.